# Javascript + Uglify - Strategies for converting properties from bracket notation to dot notation

Tags: javascript, uglifyjs

Using uglifiers in Javascript, we alter the names of variables. If we want to keep the name, we declare them as strings

```
function(){
     this.prop_A = 'Some property that will be minified';

     this['prop_B'] = 'Some property whose name wont be minified';
};
```

In my application, I have all the variable names declared as strings. So I have a bunch of config parameters as:

```
 params: {'prop1': ..., 'prop2': ..., ...}
```

Now in the JS side, I am copy/pasting these properties to config my object like:

```
//forEach key in params
this[key] = params[key]
```

This piece of code, creates all these variables in the scope of my object.

**However**

I want to access the variables in the object using their names directly with dot notation. For example:

```
MyObject.prototype.augmentProp = function(someValue){
     this.prop1 = this.prop1 * someValue;
};
```

Yet after uglification, `this.prop1` will be renamed to something like `this.a` and I won't be able to access it unless I explicitly write `this['prop1']` inside the prototype function. That is what I want to avoid.

Are there any strategies to let JS side declare the variable with dot notation that is inferred only from the string of the variable name. Like as if I had wrote:

```
this['prop1'] =  this.prop1 = params['prop1'];
```

Moreover, following that, the code piece above will create two different `prop1` variables on the scope if `prop1` is a primitive type like a Number. In other words, after uglification, that piece of code will result with:

```
{
  prop1: 5,
  a: 5        //suppose the uglified name of prop1 was 'a'
}
```

How can I automatically declare dot notated variables and how can I achieve this without duplicating primitive variables in the objects scope?

Can you suggest strategies or known ways of doing that?

Comment: I wasn't aware that property names were subject to minification. That's interesting...

Comment: @canon Well they are if you want to. You need set it on :) But in my case (although the question suggests else) I am using closure compiler in advanced mode. Thus, anything, everything is minified except strings